# Selecting features without specific character in Definition Query ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, definition-query, arcgis-10.7

I am using ArcMap 10.7.

I am trying to represent in the map using the Definition Query of the layer, Only features from this table of content (it includes 1500 values; the image is just an example) that don't include the character '6' in TAGNAME1 field values.

[image]

I know this way:  `TAGNAME1 LIKE '%something%'` in order to choose the value with specific character- now I need the opposite sentence.

Comment: Most potential data sources support a `NOT` operator.

Comment: As @Vince said 'NOT LIKE' should work

Comment: yes this is the solution-Vince , post an answer and i will mark it as a correct answer